# CSS visibility:hidden, Jquery to grab an element

Tags: css, visibility

Among 10 elements, I am hiding few elements using CSS, visibility:hidden property, as It still occupies the space in between, Can I avoid this white spaces in between, I cannot use `display:none`, as I have jquery code that grabs these hidden elements. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/yNwKp/

Comment: Look into `position` and `z-index`

Comment: Are you sure you can't grab them with jQuery even if they are set to display:none? As long as an element is in the DOM you should be able to target it.

Comment: I'd place all the elements on different z-index levels..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**CSS**:

```
.hide {
    height   : 0;
    width    : 0;
    opacity  : 0;
    position : absolute;
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/yNwKp/1/

Comment: Great. It works, did not think I can achieve this with position property too. Thanks.